# How long to upgrade MS Exchange from 2007 RTM to 2007 SP1?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

I would like to upgrade our 2007 Exchange server from the initial release (RTM) to SP1, or if it makes sense to a later SP.  I would appreciate an order of magnitude kind of estimate, is it an hour, 6 hours, a weekend?

It's running on a Dell Server PE 2950, with a Xeon 5130 CPU (2 GHz) with 4 GB of RAM.  Windows 2003 SP2 x64.  We have about a TB of disk running with Dell RAID.  Unfortunately, the C drive only has about 5 GB free; it was set up by a consultant years ago as only a 20 GB drive.  The data stores for Exchange are around 600 GB on a separate D drive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applying a Service Pack to an Exchange Server should not take more than 2 hours time on reasonable hardware. Make sure you have a current backup before you start! I'd also recommend to apply the latest Service Pack (SP3, I think), as well as the latest Update Rollup.

See the [Release Notes for Exchange Server 2007 SP3](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607233(EXCHG.80).aspx) for more information on compatibility and so on.

Comment: I did this last November, it took me about an hour I think on some decent hardware. I believe there is a later service pack and also an update rollup available.

Comment: Can I go straight to SP3 without having to go through the intermediate SP1, 2, etc?

Comment: I think you have to go to SP1 first, then you can skip SP2 and go right to SP3, then apply the update rollup. It's documented somewhere you'll find it.

Comment: You can go to SP3 directly, and then apply the rollup:

You can use the following methods to install Exchange 2007 SP3:
 On a computer that is running the original release version of Exchange 2007, upgrade the program to Exchange 2007 SP3.

 On a computer that is running Exchange 2007 SP1, upgrade the program to Exchange 2007 SP3.

 On a computer that is running Exchange 2007 SP2, upgrade the program to Exchange 2007 SP3.

 Perform a new installation of Exchange 2007 SP3.

[Release Notes for Exchange Server 2007 SP3](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607233(EXCHG.80).aspx)